# Assigning Dynamic Variables from an Input Model C#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am having some issues understanding how I can assign dynamic values from another class into other variables - I have tried using the correct namespaces, correct syntax and reading up on the documentation that the error provides - however no luck even when trying to implement examples shown. I have very little knowledge in regards to C# as I am mainly doing front end, however have to step up and start picking up some Back end oriented things at the company I work at

The current code I have is as follows:

BrazeConnectionInputs.cs

```
namespace Workflow.Connector.Braze.Models
{
    public class BrazeConnectionInputs
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CreateCampaign.cs

```
public class CreateCampaignRunner
    {
        private const string Username = BrazeConnectionInputs.Username; // BrazeConnectionInputs.Username errors
        private const string Password = BrazeConnectionInputs.Password; // BrazeConnectionInputs.Username errors
    }
```

Comment: Do you know anything about [instantiating a class](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-object-instantiation-part-i-constructors/) or is it something you didn't learn for now? EDIT : I changed the link, the previous one was irrelevant to what I was asking sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about objects vs classes. You should have an *instance* of the source class (BrazeConnectionInputs) that might be called something like *model*.

You can then explicitly assign across by creating a new *instance* of CreateCampaignRunner like `var runner = new CreateCampaignRunner()` and then assign the values in a number of ways:

- Explicitly like `runner.UserName = model.UserName`
- By using an explicit constructor `var runner = new CreateCampaignRunner(model)`
- Object initializer syntax
- Other ways are available

Highly recommend you do a basic C# course